# How to extract substring between specific characters in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to extract "51.50431" and  "-0.1133" from LatLng(51.50431, -0.1133)
using jquery.

Tried using substring() but not helpful as numbers in  LatLng(51.50431, -0.1133) keep on changes in different ranges. Like some time it can come as LatLng(51.50, -0.1).
Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expressions to the rescue:

```
'LatLng(51.50, -0.1)'.match(/LatLng\(([^,]+),\s*([^)]+)\)/)

// ["LatLng(51.50, -0.1)", "51.50", "-0.1"]
```